# Insert into mysql database, nodejs separates value

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

I want to insert into my table values which I get from my front.
so. I have

```
    const Workers = function (workers) {
        this.id = workers.id,
        this.workers = workers.workers,
        this.room = workers.room,
        this.team = workers.team,
        this.city = workers.city,
        this.hotel_name = workers.hotel_name,
        this.address = workers.address
    };

    Workers.create = (newWorkers, result) => {
  sql.query(`INSERT INTO rooms_split (workers, room, hotel_name, address, createdAt, updatedAt) VALUES( ? , ? , ? , ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT )`,
    [newWorkers.workers, newWorkers.room, newWorkers.hotel_name, newWorkers.address], (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
        return;
      }
      console.log("created splitted room: ", {
        id: res.insertId,
        ...newWorkers
      });
      result(null, {
        id: res.insertId,
        ...newWorkers
      });
    });
};
```

And there is my controller

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  console.log("body " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
  }

  const workers = new Workers({
    workers: req.body.workers,
    room: req.body.room,
    hotel_name: req.body.hotel_name,
    address: req.body.address
  });

  Workers.create(workers, (err, data) => {

    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Alias."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
}
```

Output from

```
console.log("body " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

is

`body {"workers":["John Snow","Juri Boyka"],"room":"45","hotel_name":"Test Hamburg","address":"Hamburg 5, test Strase"}`

and it looks fine but when is time to insert it into table I got error

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Juri Boyka', `room` = '45', `team` = NULL, `city` = NULL, `hotel_na' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO rooms_split SET `id` = NULL, `workers` = 'John Snow', 'Juri Boyka', `room` = '45', `team` = NULL, `city` = NULL, `hotel_name` = 'Test Hamburg', `address` = 'Hamburg 5, test Strase'"
}
```

I kniw what this error means but I have no idea why when I want to make query nodejs(?) separates my value so instead ['something','something2'] I got 'something', 'something2' and he is right that there are not enough columns

Comment: What is the SQL data type for workers column? Also, what is the expected number of entries on rooms_split? Do you need one entry per worker in that table (which amounts to 2 rows in your case)?

Comment: is varchar. No I want put all workers into one column (workers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`[newWorkers.workers, newWorkers.room, newWorkers.hotel_name, newWorkers.address]`

to

`[newWorkers.workers.join(), newWorkers.room, newWorkers.hotel_name, newWorkers.address]`

since the workers data type in MySQL is varchar. Therefore, you'll need to stringify your incoming `workers` array

Comment: that's it. Now works. It is correct way to do it? Or I should change it soon?

Comment: It all depends on the context. If the workers column is only meant for auditing, I believe the table structure should be fine. Now if you need to use that column in other ways (such as querying by worker etc.), the table structure is not optimal. In fact it is not even in 1NF according to the Normal Forms standards due to the presence of array data types. If the workers column in meant for non-auditing purposes, I suggest you normalize the table design by creating a separate table to store the rooms_split_workers mapping.